# Разница между объявлениями extern

Tags: c++

В чём разница между следующими объявлениями?

```
extern "C" int a;
extern "C" { int b; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тип языковой линковки в обоих случаях у переменных получается одинаковым - "C". Но разница заключается в том, что первый вариант является только *объявлением, но не определением* переменной `a`. Второй вариант является *определением* переменной `b`.

Если добавить в данные объявления явный инициализатор, то тогда оба станут *определениями* и какая-либо разница между ними полностью пропадет

```
extern "C" int a = 0;
extern "C" { int b = 0; }
```